# MS-Word 2010 can't unescape HTML entity e.g. &mdash; &rsquo;&rdquo;

Tags: html, jsp, struts2, ms-word, entities

I was using a JSP and struts2-core-2.0.6.jar and ognl-2.6.11.jar to generate a MS-Word.It was work perfect.But when i upgrade to struts2-core-2.3.28.1.jar and ognl-3.0.14.jar,the MS-Word can't open.Because some special HTML characters such as `—` being escape as `&mdash;` by struts tag `<s:property>` in the higher version jar.But MS-Word can't recognize `&mdash;`.
For example,I have a field called "nameAndURL" in the database table saved String contained "—" with url,like this:

```
vincent—http://localhost/a/http.action?dataFormat=html&amp;ymdhms=20130101000000
```

and for some reason I can't convert my data to that :

```
vincent&mdash;http://localhost/a/http.action?dataFormat=html&amp;ymdhms=20130101000000
```

or:

```
vincent—http://localhost/a/http.action?dataFormat=html&ymdhms=20130101000000
```

jsp code:

```
<s:iterator value="nameAndURL">
    <w:p wsp:rsidR="00AA5956" wsp:rsidRDefault="00571D82">
        <w:pPr>
            <w:ind w:left="426" w:first-line-chars="0" w:first-line="0" />
            <w:jc w:val="left" />
        </w:pPr>
        <w:r>
            <w:rPr>
                <wx:font wx:val="宋体" />
                <w:sz w:val="18" />
                <w:sz-cs w:val="18" />
            </w:rPr>
            <w:t><s:property escapeHtml="true"/></w:t>
        </w:r>
    </w:p>
</s:iterator>
```

The question is when I use `<s:property value="nameAndURL" escapeHtml="true"/>`,the character  `—` would be escape as `&mdash;` MS-Word can't recognize. The wrong code of MS-Word just like that :

```
<w:r>                                                                                     
    <w:t>vincent&mdash;http://localhost/a/http.action?dataFormat=html&amp;ymdhms=20130101000000</w:t>
</w:r>
```

But if I try to use `<s:property value="nameAndURL" escapeHtml="false"/>`,the character "—" would be unescape as `—` MS-Word can recognize,but `&amp;` would be unescape as `&` MS-Word can't recognize.The wrong code of  MS-Word just like that:

```
<w:r>                                                                                     
    <w:t>vincent—http://localhost/a/http.action?dataFormat=html&ymdhms=20130101000000</w:t>
</w:r>
```

How can i make MS-Word able to recognized `&mdash;` or `&`? Or how can i make `<s:property>` unescape `—` but escape `&amp`?
And why the "—" being escape as `&mdash;` after i upgrade to struts2-core-2.3.28.1.jar and ognl-3.0.14.jar?
Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to escape only `&`, I'd suggest you to **do it server-side**, in the action (or in a business layer), keeping the rest unescaped in the page.

This way you'll be less safe, however, so you should also strip *at least* `<script>` blocks.

Comment: Finally,i used JSTL in JSP to resolved that.Thanks a lot!